# Logback RollingFileAppender Not Working

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have the following `logback.xml` file:

```
<configuration>

    <!--Daily rolling file appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/api.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/api/api.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
          <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

      <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </root>
</configuration>
```

My log file is working just fine. The folling file aspect however is not. Instead of gzipping the file and moving it into the api folder, it is putting it in the same directory and renaming it to

`api.log(string of numbers).tmp`

e.g.

`api.log849916939395200.tmp`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try checking the following. Does the api folder exist under logs? Does  it have the requisite permissions for writing? Does the user under which the app runs have permission to write to the folder? This might be a start

Comment: @myqyl4 The permissions issue sounds very promising. I feel like this is probably the solution but will not know until tomorrow when my file logs roll. If you post an answer I will accept it then however.

Answer (score 10):

Just remove the file tag from appender. Use something like this,

```
<appender name="contentDeliveryLogAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <!-- daily rollover -->
    <fileNamePattern>${ICEX_HOME}/logs/content-delivery.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- keep 1 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} H:${HOSTNAME} - SC:%X{optionalParam} %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

This is working for me as recommended by documentation of logback [here](http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#renamingError)

Comment: but what about compressing?

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue. To fix this issue change the pattern to
    `/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/api/api.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz`.

You missed the `%i` in the end.

Comment: Yep, in my case adding the %i was the key to success ! thanks